# Can I test pageviews in localhost?

Tags: webtrends

Let me explain better: I must add some functions to track pages, but I don't have permission to access our company WebTrends account.

So, I'm testing on my localhost before asking to the responsible for WebTrends if he saw anything, and I don't know if will work..

Example:
From `localhost/solutions/default.asp?tab=products` I have a button which needs to have click counting:

```
dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcssip','www.realdomainname.com','DCS.dcsuri','/solutions/default.asp','DCS.dcsqry','tab=Products');
// generating a page view to: http://www.webtrends.com/solutions/default.asp?tab=products
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Install httpfox for firefox, open the plugin to listen to the http traffic, access your page from localhost and look for a gif request to statse.webtrends.com: if you find it, the tag works, if not, there's an issue...

Comment: I'm already using Firebug for this, all related requests return status code 200, but I was in doubt if WebTrends have any internal validation to make sure the accessed page belongs to a specific registered domain.

Comment: yes, they do have "validation", but they are applied when the data is processed and loaded into a reporting profile. If your tag fires and you see the gif request go through, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Lothaire, I'll trust you! :)